# Don't display horizontal scroll when tooltip show near the right side?

Tags: css, horizontal-scrolling

I have a problem with CSS, everything seem to be ok but when a tooltip show near the right side of browser windows, it also display horizontal scroll bar. This is very ugly. Pleas see attach image bellow:
[image]

The tooltip component has CSS:

```
z-index: 1000;
position: absolute;
```

Can any one tell me how to get rid of this situation. Thanks you very much!

Comment: You better change the position of the tooltip to start from right.

Comment: Tooltip placement can be really annoying near the edges. Checkout [popper.js](https://popper.js.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Change position of the tooltip or decrease tooltip-width.